# Appending multiple files to a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am trying run a python code to input multiple text file (for example ABC.txt and XYZ.txt) and create multiple CSV files with the output (for example ABC.csv and XYZ.csv containing outputs for text files respectively). Here is the code I am using:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3Beta
import urllib.request
import codecs
import csv
import os
import re
import sys
import collections
import glob
import xlwt
ipath = 'C:/TEMP/' # input folder
opath = 'C:/TEMP/matrix/' # output folder
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3Beta(
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api',
    username='ID',
    password='Pass',
    version='2016-02-11')
path = 'C:/TEMP/*.txt'   
file = glob.glob(path)
# iterate over the list getting each file 
for fle in file:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
    with open(fle) as f:
        text = f.read

    # tone analysis
    data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')

    # iterate through tone analysis data
    tonename=[]; tonescore=[]
    for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
        for tone in cat['tones']:
             tonename.append(tone['tone_name'])
             tonescore.append(tone['score'])
             print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])

    # output tone name and score to file
    output = fle.replace('.txt', '')     
    with open(opath +output+ '_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1) 
        for i in tonename:
             writer.writerow([i])
```

Above code is taking two files as inputs 'Testdata' and 'Testdata-copy'> When I run this code I get following error:

Invalid argument: 'C:/TEMP/matrix/C:/TEMP\Testdata - Copy_tonename.csv'

I guess when the code tries to append the second file it takes the entire path as an argument. I am not sure how to get around it. Any inputs here will be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: looks like `with open(opath +output+ '_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:` might be the problem. Check your value of the output variable

Comment: Yup I agree since I am using glob  when the code iterates through the path it gives an error. Problem is I am not sure about a workaround.

Comment: look at your traceback: your slashes are not consistent. [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) might be of some use to you